# How to use Ionic Cloud with Angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-cloud

I've reached a bit of a dead-end and I am not sure how to proceed. I have developed my Web Application on `Angular 1.5.9`. I have just now ported over my web app to the Ionic App using `ionic start app_name`. Everything is working as it should. However, my next step is to set-up the `deploy` and ionic services. At first I tried adding `ionic add ionic-platform-web-client`. But since its deprecated and from reading the recent [docs](http://docs.ionic.io/setup.html#setup), I understood I should now use ionic cloud. So I installed ionic cloud using `npm install @ionic/cloud-angular --save`. I then got the dependency error saying that:

```
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@^2.1.1 || ^4.0.0
```

So looking into it further, I realised that I need to have Angular 2 for it and also to complete the ionic cloud configuration, I also need to update the `src/app/app.module.ts` file. My questions are:

**How can I use Angular 2 when I am using Angular 1.5.6 for my Web App? Rewriting my Angular 1.5 app to Angular 2 is not feasible. Can I use both simultaneously? If so, how? How can I resolve this?**

Any help will be great since I cannot find any info on using the latest ionic cloud with Angular 1.5. My current set-up is:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1
ios-sim version: 5.0.13 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v7.9.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002
Angular: 1.5.9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic Cloud Client can be used with Ionic 1 / Angular 1.5. This is what I did:

**Install Ionic Cloud:**

```
npm install @ionic/cloud --save
```

**Copy the files to `www/lib` directory:**

```
cp node_modules/@ionic/cloud/dist/bundle/ionic.cloud.min.js www/lib
```

**Include the link in your project’s `index.html`:**

```
<script src="lib/ionic.cloud.min.js"></script>
```

**Set the Platform to assign your app a unique app id and api key:**

```
ionic io init
```

**Install Caodova's deploy plugin:**

```
cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-deploy --save
```

**Inject Deploy dependency `ionic.cloud` to the Angular module:**

```
angular.module('application', ['ionic.cloud']) ...
```

**Do the Deploy Check using `$ionicDeploy` inside the `.run` Block of the Angular 1.5 config file.**

```
.run(function($ionicDeploy) {
       $ionicDeploy.check().then(function(snapshotAvailable) {
                if (snapshotAvailable) {
                  // When snapshotAvailable is true, you can apply the snapshot
                  $ionicDeploy.download().then(function() {
                    $ionicDeploy.extract().then(function() {
                       $ionicDeploy.load();
                    });
                  });
                }
       }); // end deploy check
};
```

Thats it! It was simpler than I though. Here is the link to the Docs for more info: http://docs.ionic.io/setup.html#installation